# How do I make VLC completely disable xscreensaver?

Tags: vlc, xmonad, xscreensaver

There are some Internet hits for this query, but none has a satisfying answer.

How can I make VLC and xscreensaver play nice together on Ubuntu 12.10 (using xmonad, not Unity or GNOME or anything)?

I want any fullscreen application (in xmonad) and VLC to completely disable xscreensaver from taking any automatic actions. Essentially if VLC changed xscreensaver.timeout to infinity while playing, that would be perfect.

I **do not** want to have to run a shell script to disable the screensaver.

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to disable the screensaver in fullscreen VLC from the `Preferences > Video > Show all settings > Disable Screensaver`.

To disable it for other fullscreen video applications you can try the `lightsOn.sh` [script from here](http://www.webupd8.org/2012/05/2-ways-to-temporarily-disable.html).

I'm wasn't sure what you mean by

> I **do not** want to have to run a shell script to disable the screensaver.

I take it that it means that you don't want to manually run a shell script.